# html date picker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field

Tags: php, html

hope all doing well, I need one small help regarding HTML5 date field,

I've three html date picker name `batch start date`, `batch end date`, `Assessment date` as below.

```
Batch start date:- <input type="date"  required name="batch_startdate" id="textfield7"/>

Batch End date:- <input type="date" required name="batch_Enddate" id="textfield8"/>

Assessment date:- <input type="date" name="Ass_Date" id="textfield9"/>
```

My requirement is - the user can't able to select a previous date in batch end date which he entered in batch start date, and the date of assessment date is greater than batch end date,

for example:- 
suppose batch start date is:- 20-03-2017
than the batch end date never be lower than 20-03-2017 and the assessment date also not lower than the date chosen in batch end date.

is it possible in html5 date picker? any help ll be appreciate, Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use the `min` [Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: @bansi will you suggest some other code, i visit that page but i can't able to understand.

Comment: `<input type="date" name="batch_Enddate" min="2017-03-20">`

Comment: @bansi how can i get the value of the user entered data in the first field and set in  the second field `min` attribute.

Comment: you can do it with javascript at client end. Are you using any javascript framework like jQuery?

Comment: no am using only php and javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with javascript

```
document.getElementById('textfield7').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('textfield8').setAttribute('min',  this.value);
    document.getElementById('textfield9').setAttribute('min',  this.value);
};
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sum1umqu/)

**Important Note:** always validate on server side. validation in client side only can be dangerous.

Also note you have to check if the date already selected in those two fields are valid. the above code won't check that it just changes the `min` attribute.

Edit: The following code checks if the already selected date is valid.

```
document.getElementById('textfield7').onchange = function () {
    var textfield8 = document.getElementById('textfield8');
    var textfield9 = document.getElementById('textfield9');
    textfield8.setAttribute('min',  this.value);
    textfield9.setAttribute('min',  this.value);
    if (textfield8.value !='' && textfield8.value < this.value){
        textfield8.value=this.value;
    }
    if (textfield9.value !='' && textfield9.value < this.value){
        textfield9.value=this.value;
    }
};
```

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nan98zz4/)